# Problem in writing using javascript method "Document.write();"

Tags: javascript, html

THere's probably an explanation for this but why doesnt document.write work.

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = new date.getDay() + 1;
var month = new date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = new date.getFullYear();
var dayList = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursay", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var monthList = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "october",
  "November", "December"
];
document.write("this does not work on my pc");
```

the document.write does not write anything but when I remove the other code and leave the document.write alone it works.
and if make another script outside of the one I already made then it will print out but the problem is I cant use any code in the other script.

window.alert works just fine

Comment: Run the snippet I made above. There's an error. Did you check the Console in your own browser for errors? You should have seen it. All those `new` keywords on line 2, 3 and 4 don't make sense - you're trying to call a function, not create a new object. Remove them and try again.

Comment: P.S. why document.write? That's really an ancient method, there's rarely, if ever, any reason to use it these days. You should learn modern DOM manipulation functions instead. Perhaps you are looking at an old or poor-quality tutorial.

Comment: @ADyson i'm in highschool and I am trying to learn how to code or atleast the basics of a few languages (java, python, javascript, c#) and evey basic tutorial i see uses document.write. (i'm here to get help from the experts when I encounter a problem that I cannot (yet) solve)

Comment: I don't know what tutorials you're following but decent HTML and Javascript tutorials would show you something more modern.

Answer (score 0):

You only need `new` once.
Just remove all the other `new`.

Solution:

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay() + 1;
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var dayList = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursay", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var monthList = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "october",
  "November", "December"
];
document.write("this does not work on my pc");
```